# scala parser ^^^ followed by a function

Tags: scala, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I came across this piece code of parsing string like 5*5+5

```
def add_expr: Parser[Expr] =
    mult_expr * (
       "+" ^^^ { (a: Expr, b: Expr) => Plus(a, b) } |
       "-" ^^^ { (a: Expr, b: Expr) => Minus(a, b) } )
```

According to document, ^^^ says "if the left operand parses successfully, ignore the result and use the value from the right". Then why this piece of code work? The value from the right of ^^^ is a function, not a Expr value.

Answer (score 1):

I was misled by IDEA. The "*" right after mult_expr is not 
    def * = rep(this)
but
    def *[U >: T](sep: => Parser[(U, U) => U]) = chainl1(this, sep)

Indeed "+" ^^^ { (a: Expr, b: Expr) => Plus(a, b) } generates a parser whose type is Parser[(Expr, Expr) => Expr]. Then this parser is used in foldLeft to generate Expr value